# Would minor shape shift allow a Changeling to mimic a Thri-Kreen?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, shapeshifting, changeling, thri-kreen

Would *Minor shape shift* allow a Changeling to mimic a Thri-Kreen?

If so, would they then be able to take the Multi series of feats as opposed to the Two-weapon series of feats, or would they lack real control over the extra limbs?

If not, would something like Warshaper allow for the extra limbs and control thereof needed to do so?

Specifically, I'm trying to figure a way to shoehorn Warshaper onto a Thri-kreen warrior type.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but no. Minor change shape works as a Transmutation version of *disguise self*—that is, it only affects appearances. So it could give a changeling the appearance of a thri-kreen, four arms included, but not the functionality (exactly what the extra arms do in this case is unclear—they may hang limply, or mirror the upper arms but with no force or strength of their own, or whatever).

Warshaper adds no feature that improves this situation.

Comment: Ah, I see, growing natural weapons is obviously not the same as growing a limb with natural weapons. Or growing natural weapons on (potentially and likely) non-functional limbs. Any suggestions for shoehorning warshaper onto a thri-kreen?

Comment: @nijineko Depends what you want from thri-kreen; that probably deserves its own question. If you just want more arms, the insectile template in *Savage Species* is, I think, the most effective way to get it, and could be applied to a changeling that would then qualify for warshaper.